# Merge two arrays to create JSON table

Tags: php, arrays, json, charts

I want to merge two array in order to create DataTable for google chart. I have created following two arrays;

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => Non-Indigenous ) 
                                      [1] => Array ( [v] => 5 ) ) ) 
        [1] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => Other ) 
                                      [1] => Array ( [v] => 1 ) ) ) )
```

And my second array is;

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => Aboriginal Significance ) ) )         [1] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => Non-Indigenous ) ) ) 
        [2] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => Other ) ) ) )
```

Now I want to know how to construct the following array in PHP;

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => Aboriginal Significance )                                         [1] => Array ( [v] => 0 )) )   
        [1] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => Non-Indigenous ) 
                                      [1] => Array ( [v] => 5 ) ) ) 
        [2] => Array ( [c] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [v] => Other ) 
                                      [1] => Array ( [v] => 1 ) ) ) )
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: yes, but it creates duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Try array_replace if you want to overwrite array,

```
   <?php
    $arr1 = array( 
            0 => array( 
                    'c' => array( 
                        0 => array( 'v' => 'Non-Indigenous' ), 
                        1 => array( 'v' => 5 ) 
                    ) 
                ),
            1 => array( 
                    'c' => array( 
                            0 => array( 'v' => 'Other' ),
                            1 => array( 'v' => 1 ) 
                        )    
                )
        );


    $arr2 = array( 
                0 => array( 'c' => array( 
                        0 => array( 'v' => 'Aboriginal Significance' )
                    ) 
                ),         
                1 => array( 'c' => array( 
                    0 => array( 'v' => 'Non-Indigenous' )
                    ) 
                ),
                2 => array( 'c' => array(
                    0 => array( 'v' => 'Other' ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ); 

    $result = array_replace($arr2, $arr1);
    print_r($result);
   ?>
```

Comment: it gave me 'Non-Indigenous'=5 , 'Other'=1 from first array and 'Other'=0 from the second array, which is not correct. The output I want is 'Non-Indigenous'=5 , 'Other'=1 and 'Aboriginal Significance'=0 (or no value)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
$array1 = "Your first array";
$array2 = "Your second array";
array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

[array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)